# Is there a standard for writing Hebrew words in English letters

Tags: hebrew, english, transliteration

Is there a standard for writing Hebrew words in English letters in the context of religious texts? I see a different way to write the same word or distinction between "כ" and "ק" or "כ" and "ח" and even "ת" and "ט".

To focus on my questions I give examples from real life as it's more common and more accessible then examples in religious texts.

I see "חיה" written as "chaya", "haya", "khaya". Same goes to writing city names such as "פתח תקווה": "Petach Tikva" and I saw "Petach Tikqa" (even in road signs in Israel). And "נצרת" written as "Nazareth", "Natsert", "Natsreth", "Natsrat" and more.

So is there a standard for writing Hebrew words in English letters?

Comment: Your assumption is correct. I gave the examples from everyday life to make my point and sharpen my meaning.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. But if I may share a small tip, it is better NOT to do this early as it might discourage others from offering answers, possibly better ones. For instance someone could come back with the transliteration scheme used by ArtScroll or Koren, and it might be even more useful to you. Best practice I think is to give 2-3 days then come back and accept the best answer. Glad to see you come back though !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The challenge is that there are different ways to pronounce Hebrew. Ashkenazim, Sefaradim, Teimanim, etc. all pronounce words differently.

There is a very interesting project called [OpenSiddur](http://opensiddur.org) which developed an open source tool to build your own siddur. As part of this they have incorporated [eight(!) different transliteration schemes](http://opensiddur.org/help/transliterate/)

- [Rules of Transcription from Hebrew Script to Latin Script](http://web.archive.org/web/20120308103431/http://hebrew-academy.huji.ac.il/hahlatot/TheTranscription/Documents/taatiq2007.pdf) (Academy of
  the Hebrew Language, 2007)
- [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:IPA_chart_%28C%292005.pdf) (2005, as
  used by Wikipedia)
- [The SBL Handbook of Style](http://opensiddur.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/SBL-Handbook-of-Style-Transliterating-and-Transcribing-Ancient-Texts.pdf) (Society of Biblical
  Literature, 1999)
- [Romanization Table for Hebrew and Yiddish](http://www.loc.gov/catdir/cpso/romanization/hebrew.pdf) (The
  American Library Association/Library of Congress, 1997)
- [Concise
  Dictionary of the Words in the Hebrew Bible with their Renderings](http://www.heraldmag.org/olb/Contents/dictionaries/SHebrew.pdf)
  (James Strong, 1890)
- [Coding for Transliteration of Hebrew](http://ccat.sas.upenn.edu/beta/key.html)
  (Michigan-Claremont, 1984)
- An approximation of Modern Israeli Hebrew
  pronunciation by Open Siddur lead developer, Efraim Feinstein (2010)
- An approximation of Modern Ashkenazi Hebrew pronunciation by Aharon
  Varady (2010)

See [their site](http://opensiddur.org/help/transliterate/) for a tool enabling you to transliterate any Hebrew into latin characters using any of the above schemes.