# How to make a personal siddur/birchon/bentsher as a wedding present

Tags: product-recommendation, technology, prayer-book

I'm looking for a convenient software that allows me to create and design a personal siddur/birchon/bentcher to give as a wedding present. In particular, I would like to have a convenient way to position the text in its right spot, use different Hebrew fonts, add instructions, etc.
Any recommendations?
How do regular publishers do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Could [the Open Siddur project](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/88022/11501) be of help?

Comment: Thanks! I have already looked at their website but haven't managed to find such tool. Is there one and I just missed it?

Comment: Related (with some very useful links) https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97409/mac-or-pc-computer-file-bencher-in-hebrew-and-english/97412?r=SearchResults#97412

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mac or PC computer file Bencher in Hebrew and English](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97409/mac-or-pc-computer-file-bencher-in-hebrew-and-english)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. He is asking specifically about designing, not just looking for digital siddur texts.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56866/explicit-shaimos-printed-in-prayer-books

Comment: @chortkov2 You are right, I am looking for a desining tool

Comment: Honestly, I don't see the point for developing a bentscher design tool. If you're not familiar with such software, can't you do in MS Word?

Comment: If you already have the text and you're just looking for a software to use, this sounds like a software recommendation question, not a Judaism question. InDesign or Publisher might be the program to use.

Comment: I used Word and then printed it to a pdf setting the preferences to print it backwards.

Comment: Not to discourage you, but unless you're really seeking to make a fancy design or you just want to try doing this for your own fun and learning, I can vouch from personal experience, that you will find it cheaper and quicker in the long-term to purchase benchers. I found a few places on-line that make colorful small benchers for about $1 each if you order a minimum of 100. Between the time you spend, the ink cost, laminated paper / plastic etc., I think it would cost you more doing this yourself.